# how to make laravel seeder for multable tables?

Tags: faker, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7.

Question) inside Job factory, I need to create [0 to 10 ]
companies per Profile, how to do it?

```
  'companyName' => $faker->company()->randomElement[0, 10],
```

- What's wrong in this code? Thank you.

  ```
  use App\Model;
  use Faker\Generator as Faker;
  use App\Job;
  use App\Profile;

  $factory->define(Job::class, function (Faker $faker) {
  return [
  'companyName' => $faker->company()->randomElement[0, 10],   
  'profile_id'  =>  function () {
                    return Profile::inRandomOrder()->first()->id;
  },
   ];
      });
  ```

-- 'companyName' => $faker->company() -- this part is okey.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:
in JobFactory:

```
   'companyName' => $faker->company(([0, 10])),
```

and in JobTableSeeeder

```
  public function run()
{
  $usersQuantity = 100;
  factory(Job::class, $usersQuantity)->create();

}
```